# Swapping the data in the submatrix efficiently

Tags: c#, matrix, swap

I need to swap the data in the matrix using C#. You can imagine this swap as it is like in the matrix transposition.

```
| a11 a21 |   --->  | a11 a12 |
| a12 a22 |         | a21 a22 |
```

I have written this code for this purpose;

```
  public void SwapSubMatrix(int xStart, int yStart, int size)
  {

       for (int i = xStart; i < xStart + size; i++)
       {
            for (int j = yStart; j < yStart + size; j++)
            {

                  this.temp = this.matrix[i, j];
                  this.matrix[i, j] = this.matrix[i - size, j + size];
                  this.matrix[i - size, j + size] = this.temp;
            }
       }
   }
```

Basically, I am passing the `a21's column and row position and the size of the it`, then it changes the values between `a21` and `a12`

It completely works, but I'm wondering is there another way to do it fast. Because in my situation even milliseconds are so important. If is there another way that uses caches efficiently or a helper function to do this (like memcpy or sth like it in the C) , I would like to know.

Answer (score 1):

You can shave off more than half the work by only looping through half the matrix, as you process two cells in one step and you never need to change anything on the diagonale:

```
  public void TransposeMatrix(int xStart, int yStart, int size)
  {
    int i = xStart, j = yStart;
    while (j < yStart + size)
    {
        this.temp = this.matrix[i, j];
        this.matrix[i,j] = this.matrix[j, i];
        this.matrix[j, i] = this.temp;
        i++;
        if (i >= j)
        {
            j++;
            i = xStart;
        }       
    }
  }
```

So a 5x5 matrix only requires 11 loops and a 500x500 matrix 124751 steps instead of 250000

Now if you really need to do this often, you can parallelize the calls, for instance:

```
    Parallel.ForEach(MyArrayOfMatrices, MyMatrix =>
    {
         MyMatrix.TransposeMatrix(0, 0, 500);
    });
```

Comment: You might misunderstood the question, or I asked wrong. I don't need a fast transpose. I just want to swap a submatrix with another submatrix. For now, I am doing this manually. But maybe techniques like "Buffer.BlockCopy" could help me. But I don't know how to use in this case.

Comment: Well, then you need to elaborate your use case a bit more. What is this used for? How big are sub/matrices? How often is it called? How often is the entire matrix accessed? Depending on these factors you can ask yourself if you really need to swap this in memory all the time or if some clever swapping of submatrix references can do the trick...but without any further info, its impossible to say.

Comment: To get this the fastest for sure, you probably want to execute these particular operations unmanaged and then marshal them back or use mixed mode cpp